# Nativescript Button display on tap with text background color when I set :isEnabled:false on tap layout issue

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Initially If is set `isEnabled="false"` then no issue with button layout. the button is displaying correctly without label background. But When I set `isEnabled=true` or `isEnabled=false` on button `tap` the button is displaying just like below image with the label background color. how can I fix this issue?

**Initial view**

[image]

**After tap view**

[image]

[image]

HTML

```
<Button @tap="googlelogin()" class="btn btn-primary" :isEnabled="!processing">
    <formattedString>
        <Span class="fa btn-icon" :text="'fa-google' | fonticon" />
        <Span class="btn-text" text="    using Google" />
    </formattedString>
</Button>
```

CSS

```
.btn-primary {
    padding: 20;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    vertical-align: center;
    width: 97%;
}
```

JS method

```
googlelogin() {
    this.processing = true;
}
```

**Playground**

For playground [Click here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=amiiwc&v=3)

Comment: is it possible for you to create playground? looks ok otherwise, which platform are you testing this?

Comment: @NarendraMongiya: I have added a playground link in question. you can check. I am facing this issue in emulator and actual device both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked into your playground and it looks like `span` in formattedstring has a transparent background and issue is still open for them to inherit the parent styling.

But as per suggestion [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1401#issuecomment-314774461) now you can style the span as well. So in your case you need to style the span when button is disabled.

I have updated the playground [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=amiiwc&v=5).

`<Button @tap="googlelogin()" class="btn btn-primary" :isEnabled="!processing">
    <formattedString>
        <Span v-bind:class=" { disabled: processing }" :text="'fa-google' | fonticon" />
        <Span v-bind:class=" { disabled: processing }" class="btn-text" text="    using Google" />
    </formattedString>
</Button>`